# Segment Control doesn't work when embed in Navigation Bar [with video]

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol, navigationbar

I'm trying to embed a Segment Control in the middle of a Navigation Bar, and as you can see from the video, the Navigation Bar isn't responsive.
[The video](https://youtu.be/XGuWxp6gDcQ)

Anyone got any suggestions or workarounds? **Thanks!!**
source code : https://github.com/orihpt/SegemantControlIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won’t you try to insert segmented control without view? Just simply drag it to the navigation bar